# Copy / paste table attribute qgis to excel lose colum order

Tags: qgis, excel, copy, paste

When I copy data from a table attribute to excel the order of column is randomly. 
E.g.
If in Qgis the order of *column is **column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d*** in excel is *column_a,  **column_c, column_b**,column_d*

I've tried to change past format destination but with no result

Comment: Maybe you could open directly the *.dbf file with Excel (if the data source is a shapefile)....

Comment: If you do as @OscarCampo suggests, copy the dbf file and open the copy, not the original. If you open the original, it may corrupt the shapefile.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest saving the layer as *MS Office Open XML spreadsheet* and not use copy/paste (right-click -> Save as...). You can do your selection in QGIS and save only selected features. Furthermore you can select the fields whch you like to export. Field order should be kept as far as I'm experienced:

[image]

and then set the dialog up like this:

[image]